# cloud functions ENOTFOUND error on blaze plan

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

sometime I get the "errno":"ENOTFOUND","code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo" error when I make a https request on cloud functions on nodejs 10 environment using https library , why is that keep happening and how to solve this problem?
these requests I make are for charge my users for credit card pay.. so this error casing me a lot of damage and I don't know what to do.

Comment: I find the `https` library to be problematic for node 10 and Cloud Functions.
Instead, I recommend axios and fetch

Comment: thanks for reply @DIGIByte. don't think it is the https library .. because only approx. 2% of my request fail and it happens on an interval of time, so probably it is not a code issue..

Comment: what I would do is log the response, it maybe a regional or provider issue, or possibly a malformed request that is failing.

Comment: @DIGIByte I checked with the provider and its not a problem from his side.. also the requests are ok, because when  I send them again they succeed..

Comment: sometimes I also get this error: "errno":"EAI_AGAIN","code":"EAI_AGAIN","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname"

Comment: I wonder if it's an outbound traffic issue: doing some digging did lead to some outages recently: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/20007 
if you need some dedicated uptime and you need something stable, I suggest setting up an express server on your Free tier T1 Compute Engine that GCP offers. - this way, you are in control of the process. - not ideal when Cloud Functions are there, but I can't offer a sound solution as this would require technical access to the backend

Comment: I suggest contacting support with the errors you have seen - and insist it get's elevated to a technician as your typical support for GCP is only familiar with documentation and is paid to chase people away. 
FIREBASE CONTACT SUPPORT: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact